# emailDialog carriage returns

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

How can I add line feeds into the messageBody of an emailDialog?  I've tried "\n" and "`<br />`", setHtml(true), nothing seems to work, I still get an emailDialog with all the text running together.

Example:

```
var strBody="";
for (i=0, len=tabledata.length; i< len; i++) {  
     strBody+=tabledata[i].children[0].children[1].text + "<br />";  
}  
var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();  
emailDialog.Subject = "Test";  
emailDialog.setHtml(true);  
emailDialog.messageBody = strBody;  
emailDialog.Open
```

Comment: Did you tried `\n` instead of `<br />` ?

Comment: I had tried that, with the same results.  After more trial-and-error, I finally got it to work, (using \n).  I think it may have been that I hadn't removed the setHtml(true) that I had added when trying to use the <br /> version.  With that in place, \n doesn't seem to work.  Remove it, it works fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear you've solved it! Could you answer your own question and accept it so that the questions shows as answered?